# Can you suppress the feedback input in taco build?

Tags: cordova, azure-devops, taco

I wrote a batch script to build my apache cordova project with [taco tools](http://taco.tools/docs/build-test.html).

```
taco build android --release
```

I'm trying to run it from VS Team Services (formerly known as Visual Studio Online) Build. It works great until it asks if I want to [provide feedback](http://taco.tools/docs/feedback.html).

> C:\a\1\s>taco build android --release --gradleArg=--no-daemon
>
> Help us improve the quality of Microsoft products and services If you choose
> to participate, Microsoft will collect usage information on your use
> of the software and services to identify trends and usage patterns.
> Microsoft will not collect personal information. You may change your
> participation option at any time by running "taco feedback". You can
> read our privacy policy that provides information on what data we
> collect and how we will use it at
> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/dn948229 Your response to this
> question is automatically collected.
>
> Are you willing to participate? [y/n]

Can I suppress this somehow since no one is there to type yes or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line way to handle this case using the latest taco-cli package. Please run the following command, to send yes to our telemetry. You can also pass in 'no' if you don't want to send the telemetry. The command takes the  std-console and pipe it as the user's input to the feedback command without needing user intervention.

```
echo yes | taco feedback
```

You can then run the taco command.

Let us know if you have any other issues and thanks for using TACO-CLI.

SOak.

Answer (score 1):

The feedback option usually prompts when the first time to rum taco (Taco need to create "taco_home" in the first run). There isn't any way to disable it in the first run.

A workaround would be: [Deploy your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows), run taco once on the agent and set the feedback option, it will not prompt anymore in the future build.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if there was a command line switch that answers the prompt so this could be used in unattended build server scenarios. For now I changed my script back to `cordova build android`